# XSLT: efficiently test if a 'cousin' node exists

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<types>
    <type>
        <name>derived</name>
        <superType>base</superType>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>B1</name>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>D1</name>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </type>
    <type>
        <name>base</name>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>B1</name>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </type>
</types>
```

Which I want to tranform to this output:

```
derived
    D1

base
    B1
```

Note that node `/types/type[name='derived']/properties/property[name='B1']` has been skipped since it exists in the base type as: `/types/type[name='base']/properties/property[name='B1']`.

I have come up with this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Do nothing for base class properties -->
    <!-- Wouldn't be necessary if the match criteria could be applied in the select -->
    <xsl:template match="property"/>

    <xsl:template match="property[not(//type[name=current()/../../superType]/properties/property[name=current()/name])]">
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="types/type">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./properties"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works (using the XML Tools plug-in in Notepad++), but the `not(//type[name=current()/../../superType]/properties/property[name=current()/name])` XPath expression is **horribly inefficient**: when applied to a 200K line XML file, the transform takes **280 seconds**. Without this XPath expression the transform only takes **2 seconds**.

Is there some way to speed this up?

Comment: Are you sure you're using an XSLT 1.0 processor? In XSLT 1.0 `current()` isn't allowed in a pattern.

Comment: 2 seconds is already awfully slow, but imagine how many calculations you can do in 280 seconds... On a modern PC that's more calculations than the flight computer of the Apollo performed to bring people to the moon and back.

Comment: One thing you can do to help with performance is to use a more explicit path (i.e. `/types/type` instead of `//type`). Otherwise the processor is forced to walk every node of the tree searching for `type` elements.

Comment: @Mads: Agreed that this would speed things up somewhat; but as for walking every node of the tree: conceptually, maybe, but good processors (e.g. Saxon) will index elements by name when it would be advantageous. So a `//foo` expression is not nearly as expensive as it would be for a naive implementation.

Comment: @DevNull: good question. The XMLTools plug-in doesn't do XSLT, only XPath, so apparently the OP tested his match pattern by applying it as an XPath expression.

Comment: Use a key to index either types or properties by name.

Comment: @DevNull: no, I'm not sure if I'm using XSLT 1.0. I couldn't find any details on how the Notepad++ XML Tools applies XSL transforms :-(. From the files it installs, I'd guess it's using libxslt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure this for speed...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="kPropertyByName" match="property" use="name" /> 

<xsl:template match="property">
  <xsl:variable name="supertype" select="../../superType/text()" />
  <xsl:if test="($supertype = '') or not ( key('kPropertyByName',name)/../../name[.=$supertype])">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x09;',name,'&#x0A;')" /> 
  </xsl:if>  
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="type">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(name,'&#x0A;')" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="properties" />
  <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you - this reduced the time to ~7 seconds which is quick enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to speed it up would be to use an optimizing XSLT processor - Saxon-EE should spot this expression as one that can benefit from hash indexing, turning it from O(n^2) to O(n).

The next best way is to hand-optimize it using keys, as suggested by Durkin.